# Is there a way to modify a json string within the html while reading it in?

Tags: javascript, html, json, parsing, knockout.js

so I have a complex object structure in my JSON which is a list with many attributes for each element. I want to be able to access the name attribute and output it whole ie: "task one" and add an href on the fly while loading the text which will reference "link-to-task-one".

I'm using knockout js and this is what the line looks like

`<a class="this-class" data-bind="text: taskName attr: {href: '#link-to-'+taskName.replace(/\s+/g,'-')}"></a>`

I know the js function replace doesnt work in html docs, I just want to know if theres a way to force json to be rendered like maybe within certain tags, or if someone can help me figure out a  method to put in there that wouldn't take too much time.

Or if I'm being stupid and should just add another attribute called 'ref' or something in my JSON

Comment: can you use the attribute binding?   http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html.  could you provide a bit of your json so we can see what you are talking about?

Comment: I don't know if your code has a typo, but this could work if `taskName` is an observable:  `<a class="this-class" data-bind="text: taskName, attr: {href: '#link-to-'+taskName().replace(/\s+/g,'-')}"></a>`.  I added a comma before `attr` (perhaps this was a typo of you) and `taskName.replace()` becomes `taskName().replace()`, because you need to get the value of the observable, and it is a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not add a computed to your model:

```
self.link = ko.computed(function () {
    return '#link-to-' + self.taskName().replace(/\s+/g,'-');
}, self);
```

Then:

```
<a class="this-class" data-bind="text: taskName, attr: { href: link }"></a>
```